# Android Context menu with multiple check boxes

Tags: android

Is it possible to generate a Context menu with multiple checkboxes on clicking a button?

Comment: You can try and tell us!

Comment: You should mention what you've tried.

Answer (score 0):

Context menus generally do not have any checkboxes. You are probably thinking of an `AlertDialog`, created using `setMultiChoiceItems()` with `AlertDialog.Builder`.